# How to prove that integral $\iint_{x\ge1,~y\ge1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$ is divergent?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

How to prove that integral $$\iint\limits_{x\ge1,~y\ge1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$$ is divergent?

Let $x=1+r\cos\varphi$, $y=1+r\sin\varphi$, then
$$\iint\limits_{x\ge1,~y\ge1}\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dxdy=\iint\limits_{\substack{0\le\varphi\le\frac{\pi}2\\r\ge0}}\dfrac{r^3\cos2\varphi+2r^2(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)}{(r^2+2r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)+2)^2}\,drd\varphi.$$
Because 
$$\dfrac{|r^3\cos2\varphi+2r^2(\cos\varphi-\sin\varphi)|}{(r^2+2r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)+2)^2}\ge\dfrac{|r^3\cos2\varphi-2r^2|}
{(r^2+4r+2)^2}\ge\dfrac{r^3|\cos2\varphi|-2r^2}{(r^2+4r+2)^2},$$
we get that the integral $$\iint\limits_{x\ge1,~y\ge1}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy$$ will diverge if the integral diverges
\begin{multline*}
\iint\limits_{\substack{0\le\varphi\le\frac{\pi}2\\r\ge0}}\dfrac{r^3|\cos2\varphi|-2r^2}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}\,drd\varphi=\\
=\iint\limits_{\substack{0\le\varphi\le\frac{\pi}2\\r\ge0}}\dfrac{r^3|\cos2\varphi|}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}\,drd\varphi-\iint\limits_{\substack{0\le\varphi\le\frac{\pi}2\\r\ge0}}\dfrac{2r^2}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}\,drd\varphi=\\
=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}|\cos2\varphi|\,d\varphi\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{r^3\,dr}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}-\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}d\varphi\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{2r^2\,dr}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}=\\
=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{r^3\,dr}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}-\frac{\pi}2\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{2r^2\,dr}{(r^2+4r+2)^2}.
\end{multline*}
What follows is obvious.

Comment: Use polar coordinates and the fact that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac  1r dr=\infty$.

Comment: To show that the integral is divergent you don 't have to know the exact limits for $r$. It is enough to show that the integral over $x^{2}+y^{2} \geq 1$ is divergent.

Comment: Why is it enough to show that the integral diverges in this area?

Comment: Because convergence of the integral between the regions $x\geq 1, y\geq 1$ and $r \geq 1$ is very easy to see.

Comment: Hm, but $$\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2\ge1,~x\ge0,~y\ge0}\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dxdy=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\dfrac{\cos2\varphi}{r}\,drd\varphi=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos2\varphi\,d\varphi\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\frac{dr}r.$$
The second integral diverges, then $\iint\limits_{x\ge1,~y\ge1}\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dxdy$ diverges too. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @КириллКолокольцев: This is not entirely correct.

Comment: With a single variable the meaning of an improper integral is more or less unambigous, $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_1^c f(x) \,dx$.  Not so for multiple integrals.

Comment: Please add your thoughts/attempts in the body of the question, not in comments. And try to avoid `\dfrac` and/or `\displaystyle` in titles.

Answer (score 2):

The integral does not exist (converge) in the sense of Lebesgue, since

$$\int_{[1,\infty)^2} \left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+ y^2)^2} \right| = + \infty$$

The correct way to prove this when changing to polar coordinates is to consider the absolute value of the integrand. Since $\cos 2\varphi$ changes sign over the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, there is sufficient cancellation for the iterated improper integral to converge.

However, we can show that the iterated integrals converge directly without changing variables-- albeit to values with different signs depending on the order.

Note that

$$\frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \left(\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right),  $$

and so

$$\begin{align}\int_1^\infty \left(\int_1^\infty \frac {x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\, dx\right)\, dy &= \int_1^\infty \left(\int_1^\infty -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac {x}{x^2 + y^2}\right)\, dx\right)\, dy \\ &= \int_1^\infty \left.\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}\right|_{x = 1}^{x = \infty} \, dy\\ &= \int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4}\end{align}$$

By interchanging $x$ and $y$ it is easy to see that the iterated integral in reverse order takes the value $- \pi/4$.

**Absolute divergence**

We have

$$\int_{[1,\infty)^2}\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+ y^2)^2} \right| \geqslant \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^R \frac{|\cos 2 \varphi|}{r} \, dr \, d \varphi = \int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos 2 \varphi| \, d \varphi \int_{\sqrt{2}}^R \frac{dr}{r}$$

and the RHS diverges as $R \to \infty$. Note that the iteration of integrals on the RHS is independent of order as the integrand is continuous and the region of integration is bounded.

Comment: "The correct way to prove this when changing to polar coordinates is to consider the absolute value of the integrand. " - That's what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: @КириллКолокольцев: I added some more to help you finish.

Comment: This question illustrates some important points.  You've shown some effort here.\Edit in  some of your work in the comments to the question to prevent this from being closed and deleted.